# How to get the length of a discord.Embed [DISCORD.PY]

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I need a way to get the exact length of a embed so i can check if it goes over the limit. So if it does go over the limit, it can split into multiple messages/embeds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we take a look at the [official Discord documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-limits) for rich Embed limits we can see that the total limit is 6000 characters.

> Additionally, the characters in all `title`, `description`, `field.name`, `field.value`, `footer.text`, and `author.name` fields must not exceed 6000 characters in total. Violating any of these constraints will result in a `Bad Request` response.

But there are also individual limits as follows:

```
+-------------+------------------------+
|    Field    |         Limit          |
+-------------+------------------------+
| title       | 256 characters         |
| description | 4096 characters*       |
| fields      | Up to 25 field objects |
| field.name  | 256 characters         |
| field.value | 1024 characters        |
| footer.text | 2048 characters        |
| author.name | 256 characters         |
+-------------+------------------------+
```

*see [this announcement](https://discord.com/channels/613425648685547541/697138785317814292/860278223236890624) in the [Discord Developers server](https://discord.gg/discord-developers)

So in many cases you may need to check and handle all of these limits individually. In the end, here is how to check if the *total* embed limit has been hit, this does **not** check the individual limits above.

```
# embed would be the discord.Embed instance
fields = [embed.title, embed.description, embed.footer.text, embed.author.name]

fields.extend([field.name for field in embed.fields])
fields.extend([field.value for field in embed.fields])

total = ""
for item in fields:
    # If we str(discord.Embed.Empty) we get 'Embed.Empty', when
    # we just want an empty string...
    total += str(item) if str(item) != 'Embed.Empty' else ''

print(len(total))
```